# Ant to spin up background process for junit tests

Tags: ant, junit

I was wondering if it was possible to have Ant spin up a background server daemon so that I can write tests against the client that require comminication with the server.  I've tried creating a java task like so:

```
     <java classpath="${jar.dir}/foo.jar" classname="foo.Server" fork="true"  failonerror="true">
         <arg value="7777"/>
     </java>
```

Which correctly spins up the server, but blocks indefinitely.  If I add `spawn="true"`, I get this:

```
spawn does not allow attributes related to input, output, error, result
spawn also does not allow timeout
finally, spawn is not compatible with a nested I/O <redirector>
```

I assume this is caused by the argument, but it's required by the server and I don't know how to get around it.

Here's what my current junit target looks like:

```
 <target name="junit" depends="build-jar">
     <mkdir dir="${report.dir}"/>

     <junit printsummary="yes">
         <classpath>
             <path refid="junitcp"/>
         </classpath>
         <formatter type="brief"/>
         <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${report.dir}">
             <fileset dir="${homeDir}" includes="foo/*Test.java"/>
         </batchtest>
     </junit>
 </target>
```

Comment: You should start/stop the Server in the junit Tests directly. That way you don't depend on ant or any other process for your tests to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `failonerror` attribute allows you to create the spawned java process.